# Two Arrays to One Multidimensionaly Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two one dimensionaly arrays - each of the same length; `temperature` and `seconds`. To create a scatter graph, I need it in the form;

```
var data = [
            [temperature[100],seconds[100]],
            [temperature[99],seconds[99]],
            [temperature[98],seconds[98]],
             ...
           ];
```

I can't seem to work out how to do it, and I seem to be asking the wrong questions in Google.

Comment: search for 'zip javascript arrays' next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop backwards through the arrays and create new arrays from each pair of items:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = temperature.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  data.push([ temperature[i], seconds[i] ]);
}
```

Comment: Why loop backwards here? Aren't you resizing the array each time anyway by using push?

Comment: @Triptych: Because the last elements of the `temperature` and `seconds` array should come first.

Comment: @Triptych: I chose to loop backwards because the result has the data backwards. Using `push` is somewhat slower, but it makes for simpler code here. You can make it faster by creating the array with the final size, and by setting the items using the index instead of using `push`, but there is no dramatic difference. Arrays work a little different in various browsers, in Firefox for example it doesn't make any difference at all if you create the array with the final size or create an empty array and let it grow.

Comment: @Guffa - I missed the obvious reason - that it was reversed in the OP's output. Good info about push behavior tho - thanks =). And I should have said "-potentially- resizing the array"

Comment: @Triptych Thanks for that :) The array was used in a scatter plot, so the ordering ending up being unimportant (whereas when I was trending just a line, it was). Worked great nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

I think this the solution to your problem, though not tested.

```
data = [];
for(var i = 0, len = temperature.lengh - 1;i < len; i++){
  data[i] = [temperature[len  - i] , seconds[len - i]];
}
```

Comment: I think on the line inside the loop the `[len - i]` indexes should be `[len - i - 1]`, because the last item in the array is at an index equal to the length minus 1. Either that or change the loop initialisation and condition: `for(var i=0; len=temperature.length-1; i<=len; i++)`.